# What is the name of the soundtrack playing in One Piece episode 527 when Sanji cries on Fishman Island?

Tags: one-piece, music

[image: When Sanji cries]

Is there anyone who can tell me which soundtrack this is? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [**Resort Island**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64bfT-NBWMM) from One Piece Movie 6 OST.